# sentinelsat Python API error in download

Tags: python, geojson, api, sentinel-2, sentinel-hub

I am having a go at using the sentinelsat python API to download satellite imagery. However, I am receiving error messages when I try to convert to a pandas dataframe. This code works and downloads my requested sentinel satellite images:

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
from datetime import date

api = SentinelAPI('*****', '*****', 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')

footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('testAPIpoly.geojson'))

products = api.query(footprint, cloudcoverpercentage = (0,10))

#this works  
api.download_all(products)
```

However if I instead attempt to convert to a pandas dataframe

```
#api.download_all(products)

#this does not work
products_df = api.to_dataframe(products)

api.download_all(products_df)
```

I receive an extensive error message that includes

> "sentinelsat.sentinel.SentinelAPIError: HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error: InvalidKeyException : Invalid key (title) to access Products
>   "

(where (title) is also replaced with **processed**, **platformname**, **processingbaseline**, etc.). I've tried a few different ways to convert to a dataframe and filter/sort results and have received an error message every time (note: I have pandas/geopandas installed). How can I convert to a dataframe and filter/sort with the sentinelsat API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [#216](https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat/issues/216): "The download_all method does not accept a DataFrame as input. However, you can use the index in the dataframe as a direct input to the download method."

```
api.download_all(products_df.index)
```